# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04: Prevent the display from turning off when locking screen

Tags: display, monitor, lock-screen

When I lock the screen with Super + L keyboard shortcut, the screen gets locked and all displays turn off. I want to keep them on when locking the screen.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/ this extension is the one you need to install and use.

for Ubuntu 20.04 download the version 3.36

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been googling for days